# AngularFire 3-way data binding is not updating firebase when a checkbox change

Tags: javascript, angularjs, data-binding, firebase, angularfire

I'm developing a simple todo app with Angular and Firebase using AngularFire module.

So I have a boolean attribute in my model represented by a checkbox in the template, the problem is that I'm trying to use the three way data binding from AngularFire using the `$bind` method to keep the all changes syncronized (firebase data, DOM and ng-model) but the firebase data is not updating when I select a checkbox.

Here's my controller where I'm using the AngularFire `$bind` method:

```
angular.module('singularPracticeApp')
  .controller('TodoCtrl', ['$scope', 'TodoService', function ($scope, todoService) {
    $scope.todos = todoService;

    $scope.todos.$bind($scope, 'todo.done');

    $scope.addTodo = function () {
      $scope.todos.$add({text: $scope.todoText, done:false});
      $scope.todoText = '';
    };

    $scope.remaining = function () {
      var count = -11;
      angular.forEach($scope.todos, function(todo){
        count += todo.done? 0 : 1;
      });
      return count;
    };

    $scope.clear = function (id) {
      $scope.todos.$remove(id);
    };
  }]);
```

And here is the tempalte file:

```
<div ng-controller="TodoCtrl">
  <h4>Task runner</h4>
  <span>{{remaining()}} todos left.</span>
  <ul>
    <li ng-repeat="(id, todo) in todos">
      <input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done">
      <span ng-if="todo.done" style="color: #ddd;">{{todo.text}}</span>
      <span ng-if="todo.done == false">{{todo.text}}</span>
      <small ng-if="todo.done"><a href="" ng-click="clear(id)">clear</a></small>
    </li>
  </ul>
  <form ng-submit="addTodo()">
    <input type="text" ng-model="todoText" placeholder="New todo item">
    <input type="submit" class="btn btn-primary" value="add">
  </form>
</div>
```

Am I missing something? Is really possible to make this work with a simple checkbox?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: You haven't specified a todo object but you've bound to one of its properties (todo.done). What happens if you just bind on $scope.done or some more direct path?

Comment: @Kato Nothing happens. I just updated the question with the full template code. I hope it helps somehow.

Comment: Kato, can you help me with this?
http://stackoverflow.com/questions/37847600/live-realtime-3-ways-data-binding-date-time-input-on-angularfire

Answer (score 9, accepted):

You haven't included todoService here so it's going to be difficult to give you an accurate answer. I'll assume that todoService returns a $firebase instance containing the `todos` since that seems likely. Keep in mind that the problem could be in that code as well.

Several problems you can address, which may resolve your issue:

**Your TodoCtrl is not per-item**

You seem to be using TodoCtrl as if it were created per-item in the ng-repeat. However, it exists outside the scope of ng-repeat and is only created once for the entire list.

**Ng-repeat does not re-use your existing controller scope.**

[Directives operate in an isolate scope](http://docs.angularjs.org/guide/directive). That means that they do not share scope with your controller. So when you do ng-repeat="todo in todos" you do not add `todo` into your controller's scope.

This makes sense since each ng-repeat iteration would overwrite the same `todo` object.

**You are trying to double-bind to a synchronized object**

You are trying to create a three-way binding `$scope.todos.[$todo].done`, but you have already created a three-way binding on `$scope.todos`. Instead, let $scope.todos take care of synchronization.

**You've attempted to bind $scope.todos to a property in itself**

When you call $bind, you are binding $scope.todos to $scope.todos.todo.done. Obviously this self-referential statement isn't what you intended. I can't tell what is returned by your service but maybe you meant this:

```
todoService.$bind($scope, 'todos');
```

If you don't want to automatically push changes on the entire todos list, you can add a $save call instead of using $bind:

```
$scope.todos = todoService;

<input type="checkbox" ng-model="todo.done" ng-change="$parent.todos.$save(id)">
```

**All together:**

```
angular.module('singularPracticeApp')
   .service('todoService', function($firebase) {
      return $firebase( new Firebase(URL_TO_TODOS_LIST) );
   });
   .controller('TodoCtrl', function($scope, todoService) {
      todoService.$bind($scope, 'todos');

      $scope.addTodo = function () {
         $scope.todos.$add({text: $scope.todoText, done:false});
         $scope.todoText = '';
      };

      /** ... and so on ... **/      
   });
```