# Live, realtime 3 ways data-binding date-time input on AngularFire

Tags: javascript, angularjs, angularjs-directive, firebase, angularfire

I have the following simplified version of my code:

```
tr(ng-repeat='entry in ds3.entries | orderBy:orderByField:reverseSort | filter:query as results')        
    td
      input.screen(type='datetime-local', ng-model='entry.date_received', datetime="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a" )
      span(ng-hide='') {{entry.date_received | dateFormat }}
tr.screen
    td
      input.screen(type='datetime-local', ng-model='new_entry.date_received', datetime="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a", date-parser="MM/dd/yyyy hh:mm a")
    td
      button.btn-xs.btn-success(ng-click='insert()')
        span.fa.fa-plus-square
        |   Insert
```

That is the Jade part for HTML view, allowing supposedly **adding** new datetime-local data and **updating** it live (like an GoogleDocs Excel table).

I'm trying to **wire things up** using AngularFire (AngularJS 1.x and Firebase database). I had been able to have Auth and things worked for text input field. Problem is as we know Firebase doesn't accept DATETIME value. So, I'm trying to sort out alternatives and workaround solutions for live, realtime changing and editing of datetime input using **3-ways data binding** for **a collection**.

My ***planning*** is to have datetime sent to Firebase as **integer string** (unix_timestamp) and feed back as **a datetime format**. So, I try 2 directives.

1- to filter display result from integer string for the view.

```
angular.module('workspaceApp')
.filter('dateFormat', ['$moment', function($moment) {
    return function(time) {
      return time ? $moment.unix(time).format('MM/DD/YYYY - hh:mm a') : time;
    };
}])
```

2-(tough one)- to convert and save integer string to Firebase database without showing error on the view (because things tied together in 3-ways data binding [concept] so I'm stucked and struggling at figuring out how to do it properly). For text field, I would only do ng-change='ds3.entries.$save(entry)' in the input tag.

```
.directive("input", function () {
return {
    require: 'ngModel',
    /* scope : {
                   entries : "="
    },*/
    link: function (scope, elem, attr, modelCtrl) {
      if (attr['type'] === 'date' || attr['type'] === 'datetime-local') {
        modelCtrl.$formatters.push(function (modelValue) {
          if (modelValue) {
              return new Date(modelValue * 1000);
          } else {
              return null;
          }
        });
        elem.bind('change', function () {
          scope.$apply(function() {
            var str = elem.val();
            var time = new Date(elem.val());
            var unix_time = Math.floor(time.getTime() / 1000);
            console.log(str, unix_time);
            scope.entries.$save().then(function(ref) {
              ref.key() === scope.entry.$id; // true
            }, function(error) {
              console.log("Error:", error);
            });
            modelCtrl.$setViewValue(unix_time.toString());
            modelCtrl.$render();
            // $scope.entry.update(unix_time.toString());
          });
        });
      }
    }
};
```

})

```
.directive('fetchDate', function(){
return {
  link: function($scope){
    $scope.$watch('date_received', function(newVal, oldVal){
      if (newVal){
        $scope.entry.date_received = Math.floor(newVal / 1000);
        console.log($scope.entry.date_received);
      }
    });
  }
};
```

})

I went with ng-change=UpdateFunction() in the datetime input and went to directive and controller to write the function but not yet solve it. I tried $watch too but usually see undefined either old date or new date in the console.

```
$scope.$watch('entry.date_received',function(newVal, oldVal){
  console.log(Math.floor(newVal / 1000) , Math.floor(oldVal / 1000));
  // $scope.update(newVal);
});
```

But hardly get it solved. Any ideas?

Comment: For 2), I think I simply want to be guided over how to break the two ways binding for a short while to update|$save the change to the Firebase and don't feed back yet, only feed back after $formatter in place.

ngModel.$formatters    
vs.   
ngModel.$setViewValue(unix_time.toString());

ngModel$render();

Comment: might be this can help: https://alexperry.io/angularjs/2014/12/10/parsers-and-formatters-angular.html

Answer (score 1):

Putting this on your `<input type="date" date-conversion/>` will handle 3 way binding with AngularFire and dates.

```
app.directive('dateConversion', function () {
return {
    restrict: "A",
    require: "ngModel",
    link(scope, element, attributes, ngModel) {
        ngModel.$formatters.push(value => {
            let output = null;
            if (value) {
                scope.stringValue = value;
            }
            if (value) { output = moment(value).toDate(); }
            return output;
        });

        ngModel.$parsers.push(value => {
            let output = null;
            if (value) { output = moment(value).format(); }
            return output;
        });
    },
}
```

});

Comment: I've tried a number of approaches and this was the closest.

I did need to change "moment(value).format()" to ""moment(value).toDate()"" though to get it fully working for both loading and saving changed data.